# How to animate views inside UIStackView with AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario is, I have 3 buttons inside a horizontal stack view which has some constraints, so I am using `AutoLayout`.

I want to use `CGAffineTransform` on all three buttons to animate them, but is not working. And I also can't find any reference on internet if it's possible to animate elements inside a stack view.

Is this even possible in IOS ? If yes, how can I do that ?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I had to remove the stack view to animate them one by one.